# Python 2.6 optimize nested loops

Tags: python, optimization

I have a function that has a dictionary as input and a value n.
Each item in the dictionary is a set with one or more values.
The function should sort the dictionary keys and it should extract  and return "n"values.
This function will be executed very often therefore I am trying to optimize it. Any suggestions?

```
def select_items(temp_dict, n):
  """Select n items from the dictionary"""
  res = []
  sort_keys = sorted(temp_dict.keys())
  count = 0

  for key in sort_keys:
    for pair in temp_dict[key]:
      if count < n:
        res.append(pair)
        count += 1
      else:
        return res

  return res
```

In this code I have a count and "if statement" to control the number of selected values. Is there a way to optimize this code by using some function in itertools or something else?

Comment: This smells like premature optimization. Did you profile your code to verify that this piece of code is actually a bottleneck? If no, you probably guessed wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers given so far don't follow the user's spec.

The data is a dictionary of sequences, and the desired result is a list of the first n elements of the dictionary values taken in sorted order by key.

So if the data is:

```
{1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [4, 5, 6]}
```

then, if n = 5, the result should be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Given that, here's a script which compares the original function with a (slightly) optimised new version:

```
from timeit import timeit

def select_items_old(temp_dict, n):
  res = []
  sort_keys = sorted(temp_dict.keys())
  count = 0
  for key in sort_keys:
    for pair in temp_dict[key]:
      if count < n:
        res.append(pair)
        count += 1
      else:
        return res
  return res

def select_items_new(data, limit):
    count = 0
    result = []
    extend = result.extend
    for key in sorted(data.keys()):
        value = data[key]
        extend(value)
        count += len(value)
        if count >= limit:
            break
    return result[:limit]

data = {x:range(10) for x in range(1000)}

def compare(*args):
    number = 1000
    for func in args:
        name = func.__name__
        print ('test: %s(data, 12): %r' % (name, func(data, 12)))
        code = '%s(data, %d)' % (name, 300)
        duration = timeit(
            code, 'from __main__ import %s, data' % name, number=number)
        print ('time: %s: %.2f usec/pass\n' % (code, 1000000 * duration/number))

compare(select_items_old, select_items_new)
```

Output:

```
test: select_items_old(data, 12): [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
time: select_items_old(data, 300): 163.81 usec/pass

test: select_items_new(data, 12): [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
time: select_items_new(data, 300): 67.74 usec/pass
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's my first attempt (see `select_items_faster`), which almost doubles the speed:

```
In [12]: print _11
import itertools

def select_items_original(temp_dict, n):
  """Select n items from the dictionary"""
  res = []
  sort_keys = sorted(temp_dict.keys())
  count = 0

  for key in sort_keys:
    for pair in temp_dict[key]:
      if count < n:
        res.append(pair)
        count += 1
      else:
        return res

  return res

def select_items_faster(temp_dict, n):
    """Select n items from the dictionary"""
    items = temp_dict.items()
    items.sort()

    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(val for (_, val) in itertools.islice(items, n)))

test_dict = dict((x, ["a"] * int(x / 500)) for x in range(1000))
test_n = 300


In [13]: %timeit select_items_original(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 us per loop


In [14]: %timeit select_items_faster(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 203 us per loop
```

Replacing the `itertools.islice` with a `[:n]` doesn't really help things:

```
def select_items_faster_slice(temp_dict, n):
    """Select n items from the dictionary"""
    items = temp_dict.items()
    items.sort()

    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(val for (_, val) in items[:n]))

In [16]: %timeit select_items_faster_slice(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 210 us per loop
```

And neither does `sorted`:

```
In [18]: %timeit select_items_faster_sorted(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 213 us per loop


In [19]: print _17
def select_items_faster_sorted(temp_dict, n):
    """Select n items from the dictionary"""
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(val for (_, val) in itertools.islice(sorted(temp_dict.items()), n)))
```

But a combination of `map` and `__getitem__` is much faster:

```
In [22]: %timeit select_items_faster_map_getitem(test_dict, test_n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.7 us per loop

In [23]: print _20
def select_items_faster_map_getitem(temp_dict, n):
    """Select n items from the dictionary"""
    keys = temp_dict.keys()
    keys.sort()
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(temp_dict.__getitem__, keys[:n])))
```

Replacing the `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable)` with some magic speeds things up quite a bit:

```
In [28]: %timeit select_items_faster_map_getitem_list_extend(test_dict, test_n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.9 us per loop

In 29: print _27
def select_items_faster_map_getitem_list_extend(temp_dict, n):
    """Select n items from the dictionary"""
    keys = temp_dict.keys()
    keys.sort()
    result = []
    filter(result.extend, map(temp_dict.__getitem__, keys[:n]))
    return result
```

And replacing the map and slice with itertools functions squeeze out a tiny bit more speed:

```
In [31]: %timeit select_items_faster_map_getitem_list_extend_iterables(test_dict, test_n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.8 us per loop

In [32]: print _30
def select_items_faster_map_getitem_list_extend_iterables(temp_dict, n):
    """Select n items from the dictionary"""
    keys = temp_dict.keys()
    keys.sort()
    result = []
    filter(result.extend, itertools.imap(temp_dict.__getitem__, itertools.islice(keys, n)))
    return result
```

And that is about as fast as I think it can get, because in CPython Python function calls are rather slow, and this minimizes the number of Python function calls that are made in the inner loop.

**Note**:

- Since the OP didn't provide any hint at what the input data look like, so I had to guess. I could be way off, and this could drastically change the meaning of "fast".
- Every one of my implementations returns n - 1 items, not n.

**Edit**: Using the same method to profile **J.F. Sebastian**'s code:

```
In [2]: %timeit select_items_heapq(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 572 us per loop

In [3]: print _1
from itertools import *
import heapq

def select_items_heapq(temp_dict, n):
    return list(islice(chain.from_iterable(imap(temp_dict.get, heapq.nsmallest(n, temp_dict))),n))
```

And **TokenMacGuy**'s code:

```
In [5]: %timeit select_items_tokenmacguy_first(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 201 us per loop

In [6]: %timeit select_items_tokenmacguy_second(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 730 us per loop

In [7]: print _4
def select_items_tokenmacguy_first(m, n):
    k, v, r = m.keys(), m.values(), range(len(m))
    r.sort(key=k.__getitem__)
    return [v[i] for i in r[:n]]

import heapq
def select_items_tokenmacguy_second(m, n):
    k, v, r = m.keys(), m.values(), range(len(m))
    smallest = heapq.nsmallest(n, r, k.__getitem__)
    for i, ind in enumerate(smallest):
        smallest[i] = v[ind]
    return smallest
```

Comment: You have sorted the items but I would like to have the keys sorted as the main criteria!

Comment: @user963386: He sorts by key.

Comment: Also, if you just want to iterate over the result and don't need it as a list, you can reutrn a generator instead of a temporary list.

Comment: Because `dict.items()` returns tuples of `(key, value)` when that list is sorted, sorting the `.items()` list will be the same as sorting by the key (except when keys are identical...).

Comment: Ok!THe dictionary may contain keys with multiple items (set or list) and I would like to return n-values (items). Your solution is returning n-1 keys [:n]. THe n-1 keys may contain many more items

Comment: Does that mean that the OP's example is incorrect too? Because if the input dicts are, ex `{ 1: [2, 3], 2: 4 }`, it will return `[[2, 3], 4]` -- do you want `[2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: @David: If I read his code correctly, his code would fail given that input. If you gave it, however, `{ 1: [2, 3], 2: [4] }`, it would indeed return `[2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: Why is that? He calls `res.append(pair)`. If he was calling `res.extend(pair)`, then it would make sense…

Comment: The OP's code: `for pair in temp_dict[key]: res.append(pair)` therefore each value must be an iterable. (it is equivalent to `res.extend(temp_dict[key])`. Therefore most of the above examples are wrong.

Comment: D'oh! I… I wish I knew what my brain was doing while it was reading OP's code. Anyway, I'll update my profiles now…

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension and returning a generator is a cleaner/more readable alternative in my opinion. Using an array slice avoids the `if` clause.

```
def select_items(dic, n):
  return (dic[key] for key in sorted(dic.keys())[:n])
```

On speed: I think the actual `sort` call is probably the biggest bottleneck here, although you probably shouldn't worry about it until you hit a big size for the dictionary. In that case you should probably look into keeping the dictionary ordered in the first place - you pay a complexity price on insertion, but lookups/selections are fast. An example is [sorteddict](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sorteddict). A tree-based data structure may be another alternative.

On to the benchmarks. Initial setup, lifted from David Wolever's nice answer:

```
test_dict = dict((x, "a") for x in range(1000))
test_n = 300
```

Your version:

```
%timeit select_items(test_dict, test_n)
1000 loops, best of 3: 334 us per loop
```

This version:

```
%timeit select_items(test_dict, test_n)
10000 loops, best of 3: 49.1 us per loop
```

Comment: Might be cleaner, but OP didn't ask about clean — OP asked about faster. Can you show that this is faster?

Comment: @David: thanks for your comment. I can't run a benchmark now but I added a recommendation that's strictly speed related.

Comment: Why not? Check out ipython's awesome `%timeit` magic function (I use it in my answer)

Comment: @DavidWolever: it *is* great! I was just leaving an hour ago, but I've just updated the answer with my benchmark.

Comment: In your benchmark, please also include the input data, and whatever else I'll need to recreate it (ex, that's why I print the function after each test, as well as the input data, so if anyone has beef with my results they can run the tests themselves).

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import *
import heapq
islice(chain.from_iterable(imap(temp_dict.get, heapq.nsmallest(n, temp_dict))),n)
```

Comment: Clever use of the standard library, but would be even nicer with some explanation.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Hmmm :) But outhers, who are not familiar with `itertools` and `heapq` may be utterly frustrated. I think this modules deserve to be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Fancy, but my profiling shows it to be three times slower than the original (see my edited post).

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark Just a question that may come in handy in the future. Is it OK to add (for me) some remarks to the answers of the guys like Sebastian? He has 35k rep! I think he must understand what he is doing. But on the other hand to my mind this answer may be so confusing for some readers.

Comment: @ovgolovin: I think in this case it would be okay, as he doesn't seem to bother. The problem is, this should be at the very top of the answers because it's clean, clever and also performant. However, it rightfully won't be upvoted because there is no explanation to it and thus is not as helpful as it could be. I also considered adding an explanation because I like the solution.

Comment: A note regarding the performance of this snippet: `nsmallest` becomes slower as `n` gets bigger because of an inherent quality of heaps. The docs say: `(...) (they) perform best for smaller values of n. For larger values, it is more efficient to use the sorted() function. Also, when n==1, it is more efficient to use the built-in min() and max() functions.`.

Comment: @Eduardo Ivanec: btw, `nsmallest()` calls `min()`, `sorted()`, `bisect.insort()` internally [heapq.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/heapq.py#l359).